# Information on Dakar to Tangier public transport

Tags: public-transport, morocco, senegal

### Question

Looking for resources about public transport from Senegal/Dakar to Tangier/Morocco. Any information or internet sites are apprecaited regarding bus, shuttle bus, taxi, train.

## Research

Looked into Trip advisor, Lonely Planet, StackExchange. There is information that public transports are available, but not details. Hence look for further details.

- [Safety and travel time from Tangiers to Dakar?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77578)
- [Safest road route from Tangier to Togo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5572)
- [Public Transport from Casablanca to Dakar](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/north-africa/public-transport-from-casablanca-dakar-38733)
- [Dakar To Marrakech Overland Adventure Through Senegal, Mauritania, Western Sahara & Morocco](http://www.overlandingwestafrica.com/dakar-to-marrakech/)
- [trip report Morocco to Senegal by land indipendent backpacker](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/africa/topics/trip-report-morocco-to-senegal-by-land-indipendent-backpacker)

---

## Update

There are public buses from Marrakesh to Dahkla in West Sahara according to [WikiTravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ad_Dakhla) and [FROM MARRAKESH TO DAKAR IN 66 HOURS](http://www.wanderingsavage.com/2010/11/marrakesh-to-dakar-the-long-road/).

From there it looks there is no public transports.

> [FROM MARRAKESH TO DAKAR IN 66 HOURS](http://www.wanderingsavage.com/2010/11/marrakesh-to-dakar-the-long-road/)
>   I was going to spend the night in Dakhla, Western Sahara, where the bus unloads. But the town looks about as interesting as the arid wasteland that surrounds it. Day trippers from the Canary Island, just 100 kilometers offshore, walk around seeking a touch of the exotic, looking daftly out of place.
>   
>   In terms of public transport, this is the end of the line: Everything else has to be negotiated with drivers of rattly old Mercedeses.